# How to process map returned from apex method in lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning

Have a wrapper and returning a wrapper which contains map.
I have to display it in lightning component

```
    public Class CustomerCentricWrapper{

        @AuraEnabled public Map<String,String> customerCentricDataMap;       
        public CustomerCentricWrapper(Map<String,String> customerCentricDataMap,decimal assortment, decimal availability, decimal convenience,decimal Internationalization){
            this.customerCentricDataMap=customerCentricDataMap;


        }
    }
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read [ask], then [edit] your question to show what you've done so far in your Lightning markup and include a specific question the community can answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be returned as javascript object (conventional)  which will be like key-value pairs.

So you can use either `map.key` or `map['key']` to get the specific value against key

Comment: What about if map contains any blank value with respect to the key and i need to show that too, when i iterate its omit the blank value.